# What is the correct way to remove webpack offline-plugin?

Tags: webpack, service-worker, offline-caching

I was assigned to a project where they had a webpack offline-plugin in the past, but now we don't have it and it is completely unnecessary to have it in the project.

It was installed in such way:

```
new OfflinePlugin({
  updateStrategy: 'changed',
  autoUpdate: 1000 * 60 * 10,
  minify: {
    removeComments: true,
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
    useShortDoctype: true,
    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
    keepClosingSlash: true,
    minifyJS: true,
    minifyCSS: true,
    minifyURLs: true,
  },
  ServiceWorker: {
    events: true,
    navigateFallbackURL: '/',
  },
})
```

Now I am struggling to remove the service worker created for the old clients on the production domain, the ones who accessed the website before the offline-plugin was removed, and most importantly it looks like facebook **scraper** tool gets the old version every time I try to scrape again and it is crucial since I have deployed a new SSR functionality to the production.

What I have tried already:

1. `webpack-remove-serviceworker-plugin`
2. Add the following code to `index.html`:

```
    if (window.navigator && navigator.serviceWorker) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations()
        .then(function (registrations) {
          let registrationsLength = registrations.length;
          while(registrationsLength--) {
            registrations[registrationsLength].unregister();
          }
        });
    }
```

3. Replace `sw.js` with the following content:

```
    self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
      self.skipWaiting();
    });
    
    self.addEventListener('activate', function () {
      self.registration.unregister().then(function () {
        return self.clients.matchAll();
      }).then(function (clients) {
        clients.forEach((client) => {
          if (client.url && 'navigate' in client) {
            client.navigate(client.url);
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

None of these have solved the problem for me. Deploying the project on a new server with another domain works fine. Any tips or suggestions for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully resolved my issue, it was related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/25039719/1964570

It turned out that the website was moved to another hosting and we had some ipv6 AAAA DNS records left, which took priority over new ipv4 records, so after removing them (plus still keeping those solutions for removing service worker) and after clearing cache and 2-3 refreshes the website came to normal operation and the facebook scraping was also fixed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you need **to replace** the old sw.js (which was generated via OfflinePlugin) with one that contains:

```js
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
  self.registration.unregister()
    .then(function() {
      return self.clients.matchAll();
    })
    .then(function(clients) {
      clients.forEach(client => client.navigate(client.url))
    });
});
```

This helped me to remove an old service worker.

Comment: If you read carefully, that was my #3 in the list, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

as for me , i just use a new nonexistent scope service worker to replace old one,

```
ServiceWorker: {
        events: true,
        // what range of URLs a service worker can control. Use a nonexistent path to disable ServiceWorker
        scope: '/disable-service-worker/',
      },
```

as for the app.js, i add below code to unregister old sw:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(registrations => {
    for (const registration of registrations) {
      // keep only serviceWorker which scope is /disable-service-worker/, The purpose is to make serviceWorker useless
      if (registration.scope.includes('/disable-service-worker/') === false) {
        registration.unregister()
      }
    }
  });
  // clear cache of service worker
  caches.keys().then(keyList => {
    return Promise.all(
      keyList.map(key => {
        return caches.delete(key);
      }),
    );
  });
}
```

after two mouth, almost every user have install new sw.js in chrome, then can disable offline-plugin and not influnce user